# HTTP Basic Authentication Java

Tags: java, basic-authentication

I am trying to get content from the website Socialcast which needs authentication. (First I do a HTTP Post with Basic Authentication and then I try a HTTP GET).
I tried several codes, I receive this as "result": 
    
emily@socialcast.com:demo
    Base64 encoded auth string: ZW1pbHlAc29jaWFsY2FzdC5jb206ZGVtbw==
    *** BEGIN** 
    You are being [redirected](https://demo.socialcast.com/).    
     **END ***

Here is the code for HTTP Basic Auth:

```
try {
        String webPage = "http://demo.socialcast.com";
        String name = "emily@socialcast.com";
        String password = "demo";

        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);

        URL url = new URL(webPage);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

        int numCharsRead;
        char[] charArray = new char[1024];
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
            sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
        }
        String result = sb.toString();

        System.out.println("*** BEGIN ***");
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("*** END ***");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, when I try to do a GET afterwards, it says unauthorized.
The credentials are emily@socialcast.com/demo - those are provided by Socialcast Dev at the moment, as I also cannot access my own Socialcast instance.

Is this code wrong? How can I do it properly? BTW, I am using HttpClient 4.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sending the credentials in each request? I think this is needed, otherwise the server does not have any other information to prove that you still are authorized to view other pages...

Comment: It seems that you are being redirected to the HTTPS page, have you tried querying it directly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this question is tagged with [apache-httpclient-4.x](/questions/tagged/apache-httpclient-4.x) when your example code doesn't use it. In fact, if you do use httpclient then you can get it to handle authentication for you quite easily, [see here for the excellent tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html).